# Can I access a new presentation from another presentation's add-in?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

Using Office.js, I want to create an Add-in ribbon button that opens a new presentation and populates that new presentation with 10 slides when it opens. I am able to create a new presentation using PowerPoint.createPresentation();, but this doesn't return any type of object that would give me access to the new presentation so that I can add the slides to it. How do I get access to the new presentation?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way that an add-in can get access to a presentation other than the one that is currently open (that the add-in is running in). Consider proposing this as an idea on [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform)